# Python: "Include" an external file as a string constant

Tags: python, compilation, include, embedded-resource

In my Python program I have some GLSL shader programs. Since these are fairly large, they're stored in their own files instead of in string literals.

However, having them as string literals would make it easier to keep them bundled with the Python classes that use them, and to load them at runtime. I can try to do tricks with `__file__` to find them, but I'm not sure how that would work if the Python program were compiled into an EXE or Zip file.

Is there any way to "include" a text file as the contents of a string, at compile time, so that my program doesn't need to worry about how to locate the file? Or some standard way to place/load such files that will work in these situations?

I'm only concerned with Python 3, if it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`importlib.resources`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources). (Note that this is a new feature as of Python 3.7.) This module has functions that can "import" arbitrary file types using Python's import system. It can be as simple as

```
from importlib import resources

my_glsl_string = resources.read_text(__package__, 'foo.frag')
```

Where `foo.frag` is some resource file in the same package as the `.py` file that needs it.

If you'd rather keep the resources in some other package, you can import that package normally and pass the resulting module object instead of the package name as the first argument to `read_text()`:

```
from importlib import resources

import spam.eggs

my_glsl_string = resources.read_text(spam.eggs, 'foo.frag')
```

Here, `spam.eggs` would be some Python package in your project where you keep your resource files.

---

Unlike direct filesystem calls, this approach can still work if the project is later bundled into a zip file, but you must ensure that the resource files are actually included in the archive. Be careful with globs and filters when using `zipapp`, `setup.py` or the like. `resources` uses Python's import system, so basically if Python can import the resources-containing package, it can load the resource.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!